# Error with PHP Sessions

Tags: php, mysql, session

My problem: Users are been logged into each others account without doing anything. For example, if I log into my account and start browsing, and a second user visits the site, if they login into their own account, and reload a few times they end up been in my account. This as you can see is a huge security flaw.

Furthermore, I've been having errors been logged,

> PHP Warning:  session_start(): open(tmp//sess_vfufois8rpg3p7l0fjet2p4e63, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in

My PHP sessions are been stored in tmp folder inside the root of the web server. I can't seem to find what's wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the function for the processing logins,

```
function process_login() {
$username = "";
$password = "";
if (isset($_COOKIE['username']) and isset($_COOKIE['user_token'])) {
    $username = $_COOKIE['username'];
    $password = $_COOKIE['user_token'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) and isset($_SESSION['user_token'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $password = $_SESSION['user_token'];
}

$query = db()->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = ? AND password = ? ", $username, $password);
$result = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!$result) return false;

app()->authId = $result['id'];
app()->authUser = $result;


save_login_data($result['id'], $result['password']);
return true; }
```

Comment: Create a php file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and tell me what the value is for `session.save_path`

Comment: I have two values, tmp/ as local value & /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56 as master value. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add how you get the data of the current user in the other pages?

Comment: If you have just `tmp/` then it is relative to the path the user is loading, not relative to the document root or where that is defined (assuming htaccess or similar). Try changing `tmp/` to the full path to the folder in the document root.

Comment: That's your issue. Not sure why you're overriding it, but the `tmp/` folder doesn't exist. You either need to create it, and ensure PHP has access to it, or find out where it's being changed, and reset it to the default value.

Comment: I dont see anywhere where you do a `session_start()`

Comment: The data is stored in cookies with the PHP Sessions ID and user ID token.

Comment: _Lets talk huge security flaws_. **Plain Text Passwords** and you pass the password around in a Cookie Hazus Crip's

Comment: The polite answer is this code need a serious amount of refactoring

Comment: @Jonathan You are not suggesting putting the location of the session files under the DocumentRoot where anybody can access them are you?

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, that is what OP said they were doing. I never said it was a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have set all configuration from cpanel ini editor. 
for example code like this:

```
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 300
   php_value max_input_time 500
   php_value max_input_vars 300
   php_value memory_limit 50M
   php_value post_max_size M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2000M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression On
</IfModule>
```

so just remove the line

> php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"

from the code and you will get rid of that problem. simple